# Monitor turns off automatically

Tags: display

A month ago I upgraded my system to the Ryzen 2700 from the fx 4300 and since then I've been using 1 of my monitors because I knew that I would be going to Scotland in August. So fast forward to a few days ago and I connect my LG 25UM58 to my PC, everything works for about 20-30 seconds until I thought the screen turned off, however, the screen actually went to a very subtle, dark blue, until I unplugged the HDMI where it turned black (no no-signal). The only way to get it to work again is to unplug both the HDMI and power cables and leave it for a while. I then tried 2 different HDMI which definitely works, the same issue. I then tried a different monitor to my pc, works perfectly fine. So I ordered a new power cable which appeared to work fine for ~5 minutes but then the same issue. I don't know what else to do.
Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Szymon

Comment: Sounds like a backlight problem on the monitor itself. Could be a busted capacitor on the monitor. In any case, the cheapest thing to do is probably replacing that monitor.

Comment: That sucks. I think the monitor might still be on warranty so I will try that when I get back. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, definitely claim warranty. They usually replace the monitor cost free. :)